# Adding connection lines in ggplot geom_point by order of appearance

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

I have data that looks like this:

```
             phase_f     share
1: Conceptualization 0.5000000
2:            Growth 0.6666667
3:              Idea 0.2777778
4:        Incubation 0.8333333
```

and I want to plot that data that takes a point for the shares and these dots should be connected by a line.

I tried the following code:

```
test <- ggplot(aes(y = phase, x = share) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()+
  labs(x= "% of answers", y = "")
```

This gives me the following plot 1:
[image: Plot 1 where line doesn't connect adjacent categories]

It works nicely, but I want the line between the dots to connect adjacent categories, that is, idea to conceptualization to incubation to growth. In the example, I want to erase the connection between Idea and incubation and instead have the line between conceptualization and incubation as manually corrected here:

[image: Sloppy plot 3 which should be the final example]

If I switch x- and y-axis, this works - each category is connected to the adjacent categories (plot 2):
[image: Plot 2 where line connects adjacent categories but x- and y-axis are switched]

How do I have to adjust my code so that I keep the x- and y-axis as in plot 1 but keep the order of the connections as in plot 2?

Thanks so much in advance for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `geom_path` instead of `geom_line` with `group = 1`.

From the [documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_path.html) (`?geom_line`):

> geom_path() connects the observations in the order in which they appear in the data. geom_line() connects them in order of the variable on the x axis

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- read.table(header = T, text = "phase_f     share
Conceptualization 0.5000000
Growth 0.6666667
Idea 0.2777778
Incubation 0.8333333")

ggplot(df, aes(y = phase_f, x = share, group = 1)) + 
         geom_point() +
         geom_path() +
         labs(x= "% of answers", y = "")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: worked for me, after I setkey my data.table by phase_f.
Thanks so much, bensons23